# Row height not working in bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hello I'm trying to make a simple layout in bootstrap using 2 rows, however, it appears that the height (h-50) class isn't working for me as I hoped it would.

I was expecting h-50 to be the top half the screen and the other h-50 to take the bottom half.

In actuality I notice the row heights are only the size of content which is less than half the screen.

I have some code as follows:

```
<div className="Profile container-fluid">

<div className="row h-50">
<div className="col">
<h1>Content</h1>
</div>
</div>

<div className="row h-50">
<div className="col-12 col-xl-3 ml-auto">Content</div>

<div className=" col-10 col-xl-3 mx-auto mr-xl-auto ml-xl-0 text-center text-xl-left">
<h3>Hello!</h3>
<p>Content</p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Btw if you're wondering my Profile css class is just min-height: 100vh; So there is definitely a height specified.

Answer (score 0):

The row class only takes the height of its content. Giving it a class with height would not work. However you can place another div within the row div and style that.
You can give it a class name like **height150** and add the css to it.

```
<style>
.height150 {
  height: 150px;
}
</style>

<div className="row h-50" style="background-color:lavender;">
  <div class="height150">
    <div className="col">
     <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First , We have to assign height to parent class and then we have assign bootstrap height property to child classes .

Comment: This is more of a comment rather than an answer